# Convert datetime to float with specified format in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I need to convert a DateTime into a float with the following format:

```
YYYY.[fractionalPart]
```

(example `4/1/2020 3:40:00 AM` should get converted to `2020.249051`)

In Excel, this is as simple as

```
YEAR(myDate) + YEARFRAC(startOfYear, myDate, 1)
```

but I can't find a similarly straightforward way to do this in T-SQL.

I wrote the following scalar function to do the job:

```
ALTER function [dbo].[DecimalDate] (@Datetime datetime)
RETURNS FLOAT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @yearPart int
    DECLARE @secondsPart float      --fractional portion of the year, in seconds
    DECLARE @secondsFullYear float  --total number of seconds in year
    DECLARE @FirstDayOfYear Date
    Set @yearPart = DATEPART(yy,@Datetime)
    Set @FirstDayOfYear = CONVERT(Date, CAST(@yearPart AS varchar)) -- [alternative:] DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy,0,@Datetime), 0)
    SET @secondsPart = datediff(second,@FirstDayOfYear,@Datetime)
    SET @secondsFullYear = datediff(second,@FirstDayOfYear, DATEADD(yy, 1, @FirstDayOfYear))

    RETURN (SELECT @yearPart + @secondsPart/@secondsFullYear AS DecimalDate )
END
```

...but this is slower than I had hoped, and it also just seems way too complicated for such a simple task. (If only [T-SQL supported YEARFRAC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20034135/yearfrac-function-on-sql-server-not-working), it would certainly simplify things!)

Any suggestions from you SQL gurus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how better this is, but it's shorter:

```
SELECT CAST(DATEDIFF(s, @d, DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@d), 1, 1)) as FLOAT) / 
  DATEDIFF(s, DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@d) + 1, 1, 1), DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@d), 1, 1)) + 
  YEAR(@d)
```

([SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb/5898))

Comment: it appears to be about 30% faster (since it is short enough to be inlined) and is much cleaner than mine. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this will run slightly faster:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[DecimalDate](@DateTime datetime)
RETURNS FLOAT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @year INT 
    DECLARE @daysInYear INT
    SET @year = DATEPART(year, @DateTime)
    SET @daysInYear = 337 + DATEPART(DAY, EOMONTH(DATEFROMPARTS(@year, 2, 1)))
    RETURN @year + (DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR, @DateTime) - 1 + (DATEDIFF(second, CONVERT(DATE, @DateTime), @DateTime)/86400.0) )  / @daysInYear
END
```

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is not in your code per se, it's the scalar function - they tend to be slow in SQL Server.

Apart from rewriting the code to be as inline a possible, you can use some other tricks such as ones shown in my code below:

```
create function dbo.YearFraction (
    @dt datetime
)

/*
User-defined substitution of the Excel' YEARFRAC() function.


20150915, RFW - initial release
*/

returns float with schemabinding, returns null on null input as begin

return (
    select
        year(@dt) + cast(datediff(second, c.FDY, @dt) as float) / datediff(second, c.FDY, dateadd(year, 1, c.FDY))
    from (
        select cast(cast(year(@dt) as varchar) + '0101' as datetime) as [FDY]
    ) c
);
end;
go
```